# How to remove these vertical bars in vscode. I don't know if these come from any extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

plase help me remove these vertical bars beside line numbers. Is this coming from any extension?[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67574499/what-are-those-vertical-lines-next-to-the-number-of-code-line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be the `scm.diffDecorationsGutterVisibility` setting:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you pointed to the vertical bars in the `overview` area as well the gutter (next to the line numbers), the general setting to control **all** scm diff indicators is:

> // Controls diff decorations in the editor.
>
> //  - all: Show the diff decorations in all available locations.
> //  - gutter: Show the diff decorations only in the editor gutter.
>
> //  - overview: Show the diff decorations only in the overview
> ruler.
>
> //  - minimap: Show the diff decorations only in the minimap.
>
> //  - none: Do not show the diff decorations.

`"scm.diffDecorations": "all",`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The current accepted answer is a setting for only the gutter.